# Error with displaying system messages in inbox

Tags: php, message

I have one file for messages between users, also in this file are system messages from the web site. The inbox, write message etc are okey, but the system messages are the problem.

The problem is that they are in the database but didn't show on the display.
 I see only error

> You don't have system messages.

I make them from_user id to be 0, so they can be separated from other messages. Here is the code of system messages:

```
    if($page=="sys"){
    $mysql->query("SELECT M.*, UF.username AS user_from, UF.has_pic FROM message M
        INNER JOIN user UF ON UF.id=M.from_userFK 
        WHERE to_userFK='".$userProfile['id']."' AND from_userFK=0 AND M.del='no' ORDER BY send_time DESC");
    while($res = $mysql->fetch_array()){
        $sys_messages[]=$res;
    }
    if(count($sys_messages)>0){
        foreach($sys_messages AS $message){
            echo showMailInBox($message,$page);
        }
    }else{
        echo '<div class="bluealert" style="width: 380px;"><strong>You don't have system messages!</strong></div>';
    }
}
```

Comment: And you _do_ use the same `SQL` statement to check that "they are in the database"... or... do you?

Comment: Yes i use the inbox messages are with the same way and there is no problem...

Answer (score 0):

You must save the query result first, then fetch from it:

```
$res = $mysql->query("... query ...");
while ($row = $res->fetch_array()){
    $sys_messages[] = $row;
}
```

Or slightly better in one loop:

```
$res = $mysql->query("... query ...");
if ($res->num_rows > 0) {
    while ($row = $res->fetch_array()) {
        echo showMailInBox($row, $page);
    }
} else {
    echo '<div class="bluealert" style="width: 380px;"><strong>You don't have system messages!</strong></div>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you do an inner join, you will only get rows that exist in both tables. Since I assume there is not user with id of 0, then you are not getting any results. If you change it to a LEFT JOIN (or omit the join altogether) then you should get the appropriate results.

```
$mysql->query("SELECT M.*, UF.username AS user_from, UF.has_pic FROM message M
INNER JOIN user UF ON UF.id=M.from_userFK 
WHERE to_userFK='".$userProfile['id']."' AND from_userFK=0 AND M.del='no' ORDER BY send_time DESC");
```

should be

```
$mysql->query("SELECT M.*, UF.username AS user_from, UF.has_pic FROM message M
LEFT JOIN user UF ON UF.id=M.from_userFK 
WHERE to_userFK='".$userProfile['id']."' AND from_userFK=0 AND M.del='no' ORDER BY send_time DESC");
```

--Edit--

To answer your question in the comments below.

```
if($userProfile['id']!=$message['to_userFK'] && $userProfile['id']!=$message['from_userFK']){ 
    echo '<div class="redalert"><strong>You try to open foreign message!</strong></div>'; 
}
```

Change to:

```
if($userProfile['id']!=$message['to_userFK'] && $userProfile['id']!=$message['from_userFK'] && $message['from_userFK'] != 0){ 
    echo '<div class="redalert"><strong>You try to open foreign message!</strong></div>'; 
}
```

Comment: Okey with LEFT JOIN they show up, but when i try to read them i see this error "You try to open foreign message".

Comment: i try but it's too long... how can i contact you so you can see it?

Comment: if($page=="view"){
 unset($_SESSION['unread_message_cnt']);
 unset($_SESSION['unread_sys_message_cnt']);
 unset($_SESSION['unread_user_message_cnt']);
 unset($_SESSION['mail_time']);
 $id=intval($_GET['id']);
 $mysql->query("SELECT M.*,U.username AS user_from, U.has_pic, A.img as avatarFile FROM message M
  INNER JOIN user U ON U.id=M.from_userFK
  LEFT JOIN avatar A ON A.userFK=U.id 
  WHERE M.id='".$id."'");
 $message = $mysql->fetch_array();

Comment: if($userProfile['id']!=$message['to_userFK'] && $userProfile['id']!=$message['from_userFK']){
  echo '<div class="redalert"><strong>You try to open foreign message!</strong></div>';
 }

Comment: I have added the code to fix that problem in the answer above. In your error checking, you need to check if the message is from the system. You may run into other problems (ie. what will you display in the From field when user_id = 0).

Comment: I try this... before.. but when i open the message i see only the html form for the inbox i mean everything is empty, no message, no from, no nothing... If you can give me some email or skype to contact you i will send you the whole file, maybe the problem is somewhere else...